# glfwSetWindowIcon from an embedded resource with transparency

Tags: c++, winapi, glfw

I'm trying to achieve what almost every application does, and that's to have an embedded icon which I can show in the title bar and taskbar.

The requirements are:

- The icon must support transparency
- The icon must be embedded, not a separate file on the disk
- The icon file format doesn't matter; can be ico, bmp or anything else that works.

I tried to create a bmp in paint.net, but `LoadImage` kept returning NULL. I recreated it as a 32-bit png, then used
[this tool](https://github.com/thomerow/png2bmp32) to convert it to a 32-bit bmp, my reasoning for which being to get `LoadImage` working again, and this time with transparency. I'm using `LoadImage` because apparently `LoadBitmap` isn't so well-supported.

resources.rc:

```
100 BITMAP "icons\\icon.bmp"
```

code:

```
HBITMAP h_bmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(100), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, 0);

HDC dc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
HBITMAP bmp_old = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(dc, h_bmp);
BITMAP bmp = {};
GetObject(h_bmp, sizeof(bmp), &bmp);

BITMAPINFO info;
info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
info.bmiHeader.biWidth = bmp.bmWidth;
info.bmiHeader.biHeight = -bmp.bmHeight;
info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = bmp.bmBitsPixel;
info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = ((bmp.bmWidth * bmp.bmBitsPixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmp.bmHeight;

std::vector<unsigned char> pixels;
pixels.resize(info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
GetDIBits(dc, h_bmp, 0, bmp.bmHeight, &pixels[0], &info, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
SelectObject(dc, bmp_old);

DeleteDC(dc);

GLFWimage image = { bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, &pixels[0] };
glfwSetWindowIcon(window, 1, &image);
```

There were two issues with the image; firstly it was displaying upside-down, hence the negation of the height above. Secondly, the RGB channels are flipped and I have no idea how to fix it.

So, is there a simpler way to do this, perhaps without having to suffer bmp formats and needing 3rd-party tools, and if not, how can I get the colours displaying properly?

Comment: Do you want it to only work on Windows? This seems like a lot of work to go to, converting the bitmap file into a pixel array and then telling glfw to convert the pixel array back into an icon file so it can tell Windows to load the icon file. Normally in Windows, you just set the icon resource when you create the window class.

Comment: @user253751 `glfwCreateWindow` doesn't provide any options for an icon; `GLFWimage` needs an `unsigned char*` holding the pixel data

Comment: do you have to use glfw functions? evidently not because you are already using Windows functions. You could try `SetClassLongPtr(glfwGetWin32Window(window), GCLP_HICON, (LONG_PTR)LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(100)));` and change it to an icon resource?

Comment: [The evolution of the ICO file format, part 3: Alpha-blended images](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101021-00/?p=12483) and [The evolution of the ICO file format, part 4: PNG images](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101022-00/?p=12473).

Answer (score 0):

Windows (HWNDs) uses HICONs. A HICON is a handle to an icon loaded from a .ico file or an icon resource. A .ico file **consists of one or more bmp and/or png files** in various sizes. You should use a real icon editor to create your icon. You can find several free editors if you [look](https://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/icofx_portable) [around](http://greenfishsoftware.org/gfie.php).

Once you have the ico file in your resources, load it with `LoadImage(hInst, ..., IMAGE_ICON, ..., LR_SHARED)` and apply it with `SetClassLongPtr` or `WM_SETICON`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved as per @user253751's comment;

```
SetClassLongPtr(glfwGetWin32Window(window), GCLP_HICON, (LONG_PTR)LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(100)));
```

Much simpler than I expected!